# How to detect a strong tag and add a "*" to each?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup, findall

I have this code in python, and what it does to me is to stretch from a web. The text content of the articles of the web, and save them in different files. I would like to know, how to detect a strong tag and in each one of them add a " " before or after.

This is the result that I need:

```
 import urllib2
    import re
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import time


    def _remove_attrs(soup):
        for tag in soup.findAll(True):

            href=''
            if (tag.has_attr('href')):
            href=tag.get('href')

            src=''
            if (tag.has_attr('src')):
                src=tag.get('src')

            # tag.attrs = None
        tag.attrs = {}
         if (href!=''):
            tag['href']= href

        if (src!=''):
            tag['src']= src

    return soup

def _remove_empty(soup):
    return soup
    for x in soup.find_all():
        if len(x.text) == 0:
            x.extract()
    return soup


    base_url= 'http://www.scavonehnos.com.py/index.php?
    mact=Vmcs,cntnt01,print,0&cntnt01articleid='

   for x in range(10,12):
       n_url=base_url + str(x)
       print ("#PAGINA: "+n_url)
       page = urllib2.urlopen(n_url)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

       contenido=(soup.div.get_text())

       file = open('vicentec/prod_'+str(x)+'.txt', 'w')
       file.write(u' '.strip(contenido).join((contenido)).encode('utf-
8'))
       file.close()


       time.sleep(5)
```

As you will see I want to add the asterisk to the `<strong>` tag on the web.

Comment: Something killed your picture, edit it into your question again. Grat for answering your question - don't forget, later you will be able to also accept it.

Answer (score 1):

For those who visited this question this case I already solved it and it stayed and it works perfectly

```
import urllib2
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def _remove_attrs(soup):
    for tag in soup.findAll(True):

        href=''
        if (tag.has_attr('href')):
            href=tag.get('href')

        src=''
        if (tag.has_attr('src')):
            src=tag.get('src')

        # tag.attrs = None
        tag.attrs = {}
        if (href!=''):
            tag['href']= href

        if (src!=''):
            tag['src']= src

    return soup

def _remove_empty(soup):
    return soup
    for x in soup.find_all(''):
        if len(x.text) == 0:
            x.extract()
    return soup

base_url= 'http://www.scavonehnos.com.py/index.php?mact=Vmcs,cntnt01,print,0&cntnt01articleid='

for x in range(10,225):
    n_url=base_url + str(x)
    print ("#PAGINA: "+n_url)
    page = urllib2.urlopen(n_url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

    for strong in soup.select('strong'):
        strong.replace_with('#'+strong.get_text())

    contenido=(soup.div.get_text())


    fprod = 'vicentec/prod_'+(str(x))+'.txt'
    file = open(fprod, "w")
    file.write(u' '.strip(contenido).join((contenido)).encode('utf-8'))
    file.close()
```